# SBT rerunning command with ~ when "resources" or "webapp" changes

Tags: scala, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I am using ~;container:start; container:reload / with xsbt-web-plugin. Reloading works well, only it does not happen when I change static resources, pages, etc.

How do I include them to change monitor, any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

watchSources didn't work for some reason, even when directory is successfully added there

what worked for me is

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= (baseDirectory) { _ / "src/main/webapp" }